# how to fetch data of login user in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, view

I am using a custom user model and I have anther Enquiry model. I want that is the login user type is_service_provider I want to fetch data of service provider who had login in the panel. I don't know how to do this.

**here is my models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=254,unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=True) 
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_Customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Service_Provider = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    

    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
    def get_username(self):
        return self.username

class Enquiry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254 , null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=False)
    phone_no = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    service_requied = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey('accounts.SubCategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    country = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Country', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    state =models.ForeignKey('accounts.State', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    city = models.ForeignKey('accounts.City', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=False)
    defects = models.TextField(max_length=254, null=False)
    service = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.service.username
```

***Here is my views.py***

```
@login_required
def enquiry(request):

        user = Enquiry.objects.all()
        data = request.user 

        return render(request, 'service-provider-panel/enquiry.html', {'user' : user, 'data':data})
```

Comment: Use `Enquiry.objects.filter(service__is_Service_Provider=True, service__last_login__isnull=False)`

Comment: not worked. it is showing only User model data I also want inquiry model data

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: You may need to include more information in your question. Briefly, what the system? Who is `User` (Is it a service provider as specified in foreign key `Enquiry.service`).

Comment: ok , but thanks for the answer I resolve it.